# Swtich between text with each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#mute").click(function(){
        $("#audioplayer")[0].muted = $("#audioplayer")[0].muted; 
        $("#message").text("Volume muted");
    })
```

What I need to achieve is when the users clicks again the button "mute", they will receive another message with "Volume UnMuted", instead of muted, if he clicks it again, switch back to mute, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
(function() {
  var muted = false;
  $("#mute").click(function(){
    muted = !muted;
    $("#audioplayer")[0].muted = muted;

    var msg = muted ? "Volume muted" : "Volume unmuted";
    $("#message").text(msg);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, works good, but when I click first time the button, it doens't actually mute the player, changin the 4th like `muted = !muted;` after `$("#audioplayer")[0].muted = muted;` did the trick, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would try i this way:

```
var playerIsMuted = false;

$("#mute").click(function(){
   if (playerIsMuted){
       $("#audioplayer")[0].muted = false;
       $("#message").text("Volume unmuted");
   }else{
       $("#audioplayer")[0].muted = true;
       $("#message").text("Volume muted");
  }
  playerIsMuted = !playerIsMuted;
})
```

instead of a global variable a attribute attached to the player object can be nicer.

hope this helps!